# Programming a Button to Get the Next Focus

Tags: android, android-layout, focus

I am trying to program a button to set the focus to the object that is named with nextFocusDown. Currently, my .xml file has the following

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/foo_button"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/bar_button"/>
```

I want to create a button on the screen that will, when foo is selected, go to bar.  I have tried using a KeyEvent like this

```java
public avoid downButtonPressed(View view)
{
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN));
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN));
}
```

But this is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample. Attribute setFocusableInTouchMode="true" is used for visual focus

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/foo_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bar_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/foo_button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        foo_button.setOnClickListener {
            bar_button.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

More generic way with data binding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/foo_button"
            nextFocus="@{barButton}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/bar_button"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bar_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/foo_button" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

ViewBindingAdapters.kt

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.databinding.BindingAdapter
import android.view.View

@BindingAdapter("nextFocus")
fun setNextFocus(view: View, targetView: View) {
    view.setOnClickListener {
        targetView.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

Add this line to app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

More generic way with kotlin extensions

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        foo_button.setNextFocus(bar_button) {
            // Your additional click logic
        }
    }
}
```

ViewExtensions.kt

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.view.View

fun View.setNextFocus(target: View, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    setOnClickListener {
        onClick()
        target.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we make it more generic?

Comment: Yes, I added in response a more general solution.